# How reliable are mySQL stored procedures?

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

This not a go/no go question. I've used all kinds of 4GLs (PL/SQL, T-SQL, PGSQL etc.) for database back-end coding and find very useful to establish data layer "closest" to database engine.

Now MySQL stored procedures got my attention and very interested in coding in this brand new 4GL platform.

I would like to start using it in one of my proof of concept projects. What you folks think about MySQL stored procedures? Crucial question is; Is it reliable? How "Oracle Corporation" supports MySQL stored procedures (i.e. documentation, forums etc.)?

Thanks

Comment: What's Oracle got to do with it? Presumably because they now own MySQL?

Comment: MySQL's got full documentation of most everything you could possibly want to know about running/using the server on their site. There's plenty of companies (including Oracle), who'd be happy to sell you support contracts as well.

Comment: I'd say their docs on stored procedures leaves _a lot_ to be desired though.

Answer (score 1):

Support started in v5.0, it's currently in v5.1 (v5.5 is in the pipe).  If they weren't reliable, they'd have been removed.

I don't know what you mean by "how Oracle supports it" - the syntax is different, rarely (if ever) will you be able to port an Oracle stored procedure directly to MySQL without alteration.

Answer (score 1):

A mySQL stored procedure will be as reliable as you make it.  If you write it to do everything you need then it will be fine.  If you don't it wont.

As @OMG states they began supporting in [version 5.0](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-storedprocedures.html).

What do you mean when you ask how Oracle supports it?

Comment: PL/SQL and T-SQL have been around for decades and Oracle and Microsoft improve core code-base year in and year-out. I have doubts about MySQL stored procedures in terms of bugs and functionality since sproc concept is fairly new in MySQL community.

Comment: I suppose that's true.  I've never run into problems nor known anyone to have problems but if you go to the mySQL bugs website they do have a number that are reported for stored procedures.  I'm not sure how this would compare to t-SQL or PL/SQL though.  Here is the link: http://bugs.mysql.com/search.php?search_for=stored+procedure&status=Active&severity=&limit=10&order_by=&cmd=display&direction=ASC&bug_type=&os=0&phpver=&bug_age=0